# Adding Icon-Counter to GNOME Desktop for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: gnome, icons, desktop-environments

I am looking at displaying a counter or display a variable number as a desktop icon for GNOME in Ubuntu 12.10.  I have a computer program that is running through a bunch of files and will likely take a few weeks to complete.  As it is doing this I want some kind of indication on the desktop to see how many files have been processed.  I was hoping to use a count-badge over an icon but haven't found anything online if it is possible.  Is there  way of somehow displaying a variable number on the GNOME desktop that updates everytime a script runs?

I have tried the command <> but I am looking for something less intrusive that I have don't have to click every 10 minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be able to use conky..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greeting Jeremy, based on your requirement I'm going to suggest this solution, and I hope it will help you or give you another way to look at your problem in turn. In my suggestion you need :
 
1) shell-script file "**bash programming**".
 
2) **for-loop counter**, as you said "to see how many files have been processed" .
 
3) notification every X time (seconds / minutes / hours), here you need "**libnotify bin**".
 
4) keep the script running.
***Now let's make the script***
 create a file "counter.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $( ls /usr/lib ); #just change the path with yours, it was just an example
do 
notify-send -u critical "How many files" $f
done
sleep (1000*60) # get notification every 1 hour
counter.sh
sleep (1000*60) # get notification every 1 hour
#you can make infinite for loop here 
#and put counter.sh inside it, 
#just look that up on the internet (infinite loop using shell script)
```

Finally, to make your file running you can just run it in the terminal and let it running. Or you can add it in auto-start. 
 P.S : open terminal login to root 'sudo su' then "chmod 777 counter.sh" to be able to run your script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm trying to be less intrusive so do not really want a pop-up window to display.  The reason is that let's say I leave it running for a long time then I need to delete quite a few of the popups.  I was hoping there is something like a unread email notification icon or something along those lines.  Have you ever seen that with the GNOME or Unity desktops?

Comment: its not a pop-up window nor intrusive and you don't have to delete anything. Its a notification which comes once every 1 hour and remains ON 1-3 seconds JUST to notify you **THEN IT GOES away**, and so forth. You can make it once every 2 hours if you wish. Have you ever tried/worked with **notify-send** before?

Comment: I have tried working with notify-send before and it works well; I was hoping there would be a way to have a counter in an icon.  Looks like there is no easy way of doing it though.  Anyways thanks for the response.

Comment: you are very welcome Jeremy. Well, I don't know any way of doing it in icon, if I had known, I would have told you or at least have guided you.